# Jquery - JQuery Potentially Setting An Attribute With Tainted Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

Im getting XSS issue for below code,

```
$('#cName').attr("value", "");
```

XSS exception:

CrossSiteScripting.Reflected --> JQuery Potentially Setting An Attribute With Tainted Data.

What is the replacement code to fix this.

Comment: What is telling your that error? Because it is wrong.

Comment: I'm with John - that's a bit weird. There is also the removeAttr() method if you wanted to remove it entirely https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: `value` is really only applicable to form controls so rather that modify the attribute use `$('#cName').val('')` instead to reset value property.